# Can two symbols be bound to the same var?

Tags: clojure

In clojure, can this ever be true?

```
(= #'x #'y)
```

Examples of what doesn't work:

```
user> (def x 1)
#'user/x
user> (def y x)
#'user/y
user> (= #'x #'y)
false
user> (def y #'x)
#'user/y
user> (= #'x #'y)
false
```

Comment: Are you doing this to create a singleton of a mutable object? If not, why?

Comment: every def is creating a new var, the new var will not be equal to any other var

Comment: @muhuk I don't want to do this. I just want to understand whether it is possible and why or why not.

Comment: @noisesmith I didn't mean to imply that a solution must involve `def`.

Comment: It should be possible, but not idiomatically I think. Try [clojure.lang.Var](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Var.java)'s 3 arg constructor perhaps.

Comment: @muhuk Looking at the source was useful. thanks

Comment: @Bill if you had checked `(= y #'x)` that would have been true. So I assumed you were interested in having two vars be equal.

Comment: @muhuk the three arg constructor to Var specifies the value in the third var. Which is exactly what gets set when you call def with two args.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(refer 'clojure.core :only '[=] :rename '{= equal?})

(= #'= #'equal?)
;= true
```